# How to minimize the square of sum given fixed sum of squares?

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

This looks simple but I can't find it:

$\begin{aligned}
&\min \frac{1}{N}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} w_{i}\right)^{2} \\
&\text { s.t. }\|\mathbf{w}\|_{2}^{2}=N
\end{aligned}$

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer but this seems the classic problem which can be solved using AM-GM inequality. The answer should be this: the maximum is attained at $w_1 = \cdots =w_N=1$, while the minimum should be $0$

Comment: You need to assume all $w_i\ge 0$.  First prove $a+b$ min for $a=b$, for fixed $a^2+b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all $w_{i}\geq 0$ then your objective function is increasing so the solution to your problem will be the same as

$min \quad \sum_{i=1}^{N}w_{i}\quad s.t.\quad \sum_{i=1}^{N}w_{i}^{2}=N^{2}$

First assume that $w_{i}=w$ for all $i$, then $w_{i}=\sqrt{N}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{N}w_{i}=N^{\frac{3}{2}}$.

Now suppose that $w_{1}>0$ and $w_{i}=0$ for $i\geq 2$, then $w_{1}=N$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{N}w_{i}=N$. This will be our solution.